# implement android firewall by using vpn service

Tags: android

I have to create an android application, to block some sites depend on site URL 
so I think VPNService is the best choice for me
The problem is: I don't have a third party server to connect the tunnel with the server
so how can I create a locally third party server to handle the requests from the tunnel then forward it to the real destination 
Thanx in advance

Comment: You would need to find or create the source of a VPN-like filtering server and run it locally. However, there seems to be a problem with your approach: even if there were a mechanism that could force other apps to send their traffic only via the VPN interface and not the true network interface, how would the app containing your local VPN server be exempt from this and thus able to send out filtered traffic on the actual network? **Generally speaking 3rd party code for Android can't do special things**, and apart from the limited device admin stuff, anything one app can do another can as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is there a better way to implement firewall app without needing to obtain a root access??